# Remote/VNC/TeamViewer like over http (internet)

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, teamviewer

My customer's enviroment is very secure. Only http ports are open. I have a .net based windows forms application. I want to package something like Team Viewer within the application so that the user can turn it on & the support staff in my company can control the users computer. The catch is I dont want to use Team Viewer because it sends the traffic through Team Viewer's server. I want to use my own web server to route the traffic. Is there any software, preferably open source, that will do that ?

(ie) The software should have a feature to point to my www.mycompanysite.com. Team Viewer like, but gives ability to use my own server.

Comment: For secure customer sites we are using PCVisit, which uses port 80 and can be customized to your comanpy. You could check if it does all you need

Comment: `I want to package something like Team Viewer within the application so that the user can turn it on & the support staff in my company can control the users computer` - If you're trying to package some other companies product in your product you are very likely violating copyright and trademark laws/statutes as well as violating the EULA for said product.